# Change the region to get Android update first

Tags: samsung, updates, 7.0-nougat, localization

Android 7 is released on some countries, but not in my country, is there any way to change the region, so I can get the update (without rooting the device)?

I have Samsung J710F mobile phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just flash the update manually with Odin?

Comment: Don't think it's possible without rooting.

Comment: @AndyYan I knew about that, seems like there is no way to change the region, so, where I can find official release of Android OS?

Comment: You could've searched a bit. [SamMobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-j7-2016/SM-J710F/)

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks, I googled and I saw this website, also samsung-updates.com, I asked because I want to know is there any official/trusted place